# Value attribute in an option tag always returns a string instead of a number in angularJS view

Tags: angularjs

In the following block of code, the value attribute **ALWAYS** returns me a string version of my `Id` instead of a number

```
<select class="" name="RefusedReason" id="RefusedReason" 
        ng-model="rdpt.Items [$index].RewardPointItems.RefusedReasonID">
    <option ng:repeat="rr in lstRefusedReason" value="{{rr.Id}}"> 
    {{rr.Name}}
    </option> 
</select>
```

In my Controller, the datasource is defined like this:

```
vm.lstRefusedReason = [
    { Id: 1, Name: "MyTest" },
    { Id: 2, Name: "MyTest2" },
    { Id: 3, Name: "MyTest3" }
];
```

After checking on the internet, i tried many possible solutions for this by adding the `convert-to-number` directive to my select tag, using the `ng-value` but the value then returns me the Name (for example "MyTest") instead of the id. I also tried a `{{parseInt(rr.Id}}` but it returns me undefined.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-options` instead:

```
<select ng-model="someNumericModelValue"
        ng-options="rr.Id as rr.Name for rr in lstRefusedReason"></select>
```

Comment: `ng-options` allows you to assign values other than strings to the options in a `select`. In this case it's a simple numeric primitive, but `ng-options` is powerful and allows you to assign complex objects as well. It's the preferred method of building `selects` in AngularJS - it uses less memory and renders faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ng-value` directive:

```
<select class="" name="RefusedReason" id="RefusedReason" 
        ng-model="rdpt.Items [$index].RewardPointItems.RefusedReasonID">
    ̶<̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶n̶g̶:̶r̶e̶p̶e̶a̶t̶=̶"̶r̶r̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶l̶s̶t̶R̶e̶f̶u̶s̶e̶d̶R̶e̶a̶s̶o̶n̶"̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶{̶{̶r̶r̶.̶I̶d̶}̶}̶"̶>̶ ̶
    <option ng:repeat="rr in lstRefusedReason" ng-value="rr.Id">  
      {{rr.Name}}
    </option> 
</select>
```

Interpolation (`{{ }}`) converts AngularJS expressions to strings. Avoid that by using the `ng-value` directive.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-value Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)